# MVVMCross back navigation with MvxClosePresentationHint

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have an Xamarin iOS app where I am using MVVMCross v3.2.1 to control the navigation between the view controllers / view models. I have used the `ShowViewModel<TViewModel>();` method to navigation between view models and have a special case where I want to navigate back one step on the navigation stack.

I can do this my using the MvxClosePresentationHint as in `ChangePresentation(new MvxClosePresentationHint(this));` but when it navigates back to the previous view I need the data to refresh.

Are there any MVVMCross view model lifecycle methods I can us to detect the back navigation or should I implement a MvxMessage?

Comment: Doesn't the Init method trigger? Otherwise you could make a method that you trigger from ViewDidAppear.

Comment: The init method did not first on the navigation but I implemented a refresh method of the ViewDidAppear as you suggested. Seamed to resolve the issue but I need to ensure that the data refresh does not get called needlessly. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cheesebaron suggested I am refreshing the data from the ViewWillAppear on the previous ViewController which seems to have resolved the issue.

```
 public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
 {
     base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
     Refresh();
 }
```